# ioctl return bad address with global array

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, alsa

I am studying about ALSA base on this article: http://equalarea.com/paul/alsa-audio.html#interruptex (A Minimal Interrupt-Driven Program)

Notice the `short buf[4096];` if we declare it as global, Bad address error will be prompted. If we declare it as a local of `int playback_callback (snd_pcm_sframes_t nframes)`, it run and sometimes prompts Bad address error. If we use `malloc` to allocate `buf`, the error gone.

As I see from the source code of `snd_pcm_writei`, it calls `ioctl` to send the buffer to device. So, why `ioctl` behaves as I described?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64bits

Comment: This smells like an address alignment problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That program is buggy.

`buf` has enough space for 4096 samples, but the device is configured for two samples per frame, so 4096 frames will overflow the buffer.